# what's the meaning of the function?

Tags: javascript

```
function hasClass( elem, cls ) {
var reClass = new RegExp(' ' + cls + ' ');
return reClass.test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
```

i am a new learner of javascript, i saw the above function from a book.but i don't what's the meaning of it? expect someone can explain it to me.many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the spaces are for (they should be `\b`, I think), but this function tests whether `elem.className` matches the `cls` regex.

Comment: Elements may have a `class` attribute or DOM property value (accessed by `.className` in Javascript) that could be `<div class="classOne classTwo">...`. This function "tries" to show if a rather rudimentary regular expression (pattern) matches a class name found in that property within a DOM element node (`elem`) passed as an argument.

Comment: why the code using two space before and after the parameter cls(RegExp(' ' + cls + ' ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just testing whether a given element contains a given class.  This is useful for elements with multiple classes (older browsers don't support that by default).

Consider an element like `<div id='test' class="button login"></div>`.  If you pass that to the function, you'll get as follows:

```
function hasClass( elem, cls ) {

    // var reClass = new RegExp(' login ');
    var reClass = new RegExp(' ' + cls + ' ');

    // return reClass.test(' button login ');  (ie, true)
    return reClass.test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
console.log(hasClass(document.getElementById('test'), 'login'));
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/G7bdW/1/)

Comment: why this // return reClass.test(' button login ');  (ie, true) not// return reClass.test(' div.button login ');  (ie, true)

Comment: Read up the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: why the code using two space before and after the parameter cls(RegExp(' ' + cls + ' ')

Comment: @stackoverflow001 that's just to ensure the expression will match classes at the beginning or end of the list.  Ie, `"someclass"` wouldn't match `"someclass someotherclass"`, but `" someclass "` *would* match.

Answer (score 0):

it checks if the class attribute of an element contains the specified class (cls)